# What side of the road/sky do vehicles drive on in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Within Star Wars, it has been shown that motorways exist for landspeeders and other hovercraft as seen in Episode II:

Although the vehicles that are seen in the film are all **left-hand drive**, there is no shot or scene where traffic is traveling in opposite directions making it hard to identify which side of the road/sky  vehicles drive on. **Which side of the road/sky do vehicles drive on in the Star Wars universe?**

Comment: I assume you mean Coruscant. Elsewhere in the million worlds of the Skyriver Galaxy, I'd assume there's a substantial variation.

Comment: @Valorum Is there any further info on any other worlds (or at least point me in that direction)?

Comment: As far as I can recall, the only time in the *films* that we see any kind of speeder traffic is on Coruscant. In the cartoons, we see some driving in Star Wars Rebels but it's almost always single-file traffic, same with Solo: A Star Wars Story.

Comment: Where they're going, they don't need roads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Inside the Worlds of Episode II: Attack of the Clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones) factbook, skylanes on Coruscant are ***uni-directional***. Conflicting lanes (traveling in opposite directions) are kept significantly apart, with traffic essentially traveling in gigantic aerial ring-roads.

Normal traffic is entirely monitored and controlled by computers which would seem to negate the need for lanes, noting that in the ['Bounty Hunter Chase' scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9-K1cxj6IQ) we see a range of large and small vehicles **undertaking and overtaking on both sides as well as above and below**.

[image]

Informally piloted vehicles are seen to move freely around the sky layers without *any* apparent consideration of road-side.

---

As far as ground vehicles are concerned, we've got relatively few examples to pick from (where there's traffic, there seems to be sufficient wealth that the population turns to fliers) but on Lothal we see that they drive on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the scene where Obi Wan-Kenobi visits "Dex's Diner," the ground traffic was on the left side.
Here it is:

Around the 53 second mark, we can see that the speeders are moving on the left side of the road.